# Missing a year of iMessages. How to recover without necessarily doing a restore?

Tags: iphone, time-machine, messages, time-capsule

I noticed that anything before near the beginning of this month all the way to the end of June last year is just gone.  There are plenty of messages before all that, but the parts of conversations during that period simply no longer exist.

One problem is that I can't find the chat.db file, Attachments folder or other stuff in Library/Messages from shortly before that period.  (I had to head to work, so I didn't get much of a chance to look at even earlier periods.)

I don't necessarily need it in iMessage format, if the SMS messages with attachments are available through an iPhone backup.  I do not need the stuff to be re-inserted into iMessages necessarily and I don't want to lose the messages that have happened since the beginning of this month either; I just want be able to keep the old ones.

Normally, I'd have waited until I got home and to mess with it, but I guess I'm just a bit panicked; there's a lot of stuff that gets talked about over a year and I very much want it back.

(There is a Time Capsule, but honestly, I have never actively used it so I'm not sure how to work it.)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to restore your messages from an iPhone, iPhone backup, Mac, or Mac backup on your Time Capsule?

Comment: I apologize for being unclear.  I would prefer to recover the iMessage stuff on the Macbook.  I had searched for the files in Time Machine that would at least let me pull the message database up, so I could work with it later, but files and folders expected were not there when I tried to get to them through Time Machine.  I don't have the iPhone right now, but it had been backed up on the Macbook.  The Time Capsule mention was just to say there is one and the Macbook does back up to it, but I'm not familiar with it as it isn't mine.

Answer (score 1):

Time Capsule would only help if you regularly backed up your iPhone to iTunes. Long term, I would recommend using a tool to export SMS messages to a durable format.

PhoneView for Mac does that by managing a parallel database of messages on your Mac and you can export them as PDF just in case.